# Book with a tortoise shell cat and a purple drink

Tags: story-identification

Teacher said she read this book in 4th grade. She only knows a few details.

- The cover was black green and white with a girl on the front with a sword and helmet.
- The story included a tortoise shell cat and she drank a purple drink.

Does anyone have any ideas about the title?

Comment: How old is teacher or when did she read the book?  Where did she live then (US, UK, somewhere else)?  What language did she read in?

Comment: Is this book science fiction or fantasy?

Comment: And what aspects made it Science fiction or Fantasy?

Comment: Why so it is... https://centres.exeter.ac.uk/historyresource/resources/ks2/JNicholRBritain/Roman%20Britain%20-%20Conquest%20and%20Rebellion%2031.03.05.doc will be better.

Comment: Teacher is about 35 years of age, lived in the US and English was the language.

Answer (score 8):

Somewhat ironically, I'm going to go with an answer that meets half your criteria.

***Half Magic*, by Edward Eager**, the first book in the *Tales of Magic* series.

[image: cover of "Half Magic"]

> Four children wish on a Half Magic coin that gets their mother Alison half-way home, rescued by Mr Smith. Mark's wish zaps them to a desert without island, where half-talking cat Carrie gabbles to a camel. Romantic Katherine battles Launcelot. Eldest Jane rejects siblings for another family. Stubborn youngest, Martha, causes a riot downtown.
>   <sub>-[Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/225038.Half_Magic)</sub>

A black, green and white cover with a girl on the front with a sword and helmet. Check.

It DOES have Carrie the cat in it, however her colour is never given. Nor does she drink a purple drink.